# Types of Quantum Computer

Tags: quantum-gate, simulation, adiabatic-model

I am confused of all that different Quantum computers.

please correct me if I say something wrong.

There are two main different types of quantum computing:

1. Quantum Gates based computing
2. quantum annealing

For quantum gate based computing, I know that there are different kind of architectures -- that's clear for me.

But why I am so confused is, there is the Quantum Annealing, which is used by D-Wave Systems and that Q. annealer is using the adiabatic theorem , right ?

So then we can say that Adiabatic Quantum Annealer = Quantum Annealer ?

The next confusing term is Adiabatic Quantum Computer , is that Adiabatic Quantum Annealer?

And the last is what is Quantum Simulator ? Where is that used ? which type of quantum computing are that simulated? And is there a difference between them and quantum annealing ?

Too many questions :/

Comment: Check out [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/74/8141) and it's excellent set of answers by user Niel de Beaudrap

Comment: Also note that many would argue that the [measurement based](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1347/8141) model of quantum computation is different from the gate based model.

Comment: Wow :) Thank you. its excellent